# SAML Identity Provider's Metadata Expiration

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, auth0, okta

I am building multiple providers based SSO using SAML, I want to cache the metadata from all IDPs which I download from the their respective metadata URLs dynamically. The SAML specs says about "validUntil" and "cacheDuration" as optional details that IDP can include in its metadata XML. I checked none of the IDPs metadata XML includes these details in entity descriptor.

On what basis should I invalidate the cache, what expiration should I use to re-download the metadata.

I am using Ping, AD, Auth0 & Okta. And I could not find in IDPs docs as well, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't even heard of anything like metadata validity. In practice, we have a cache of 24 hours. This is sufficient to catch certificate expirations in advance. Other configuration changes, reflected once in 24h is good enough from business point of view. Not that it suits you for sure but something to consider.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification, I see the certificate usually have expiration duration more than a year, here do you mean that I should check for certificate expiration every 24 hrs